# Eclipse plugin, ClassCastException

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to get the path of the currently selected projects. I'm using the code below:

```
    IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
    IWorkbenchWindow window = workbench == null ? null : workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    IWorkbenchPage activePage = window == null ? null : window.getActivePage();

    ISelection selection = activePage.getSelection();
    if (selection instanceof TreeSelection) {
        List list = ((TreeSelection) selection).toList();

        for (Object selectedObject : list) {
            String path = ((Project) selectedObject).getFullPath().makeAbsolute().toString();
            System.out.println(path);
        }
    }
```

However, when I run that stuff, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project cannot be cast to org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project
at junitcategories.handlers.SampleHandler.execute(SampleHandler.java:48)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:76)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Is this a classloading issue?How can I solve this?
--Sorry, I'm new to plugin development.

Thanks,
Tamas

Comment: Ah, the joys of dealing with classloaders! This is surely a classloder issue, based on the fact that both classes have the same name. Can't help you solve it though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that what you are trying to access is a Workbench project you should cast to the interface `org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject`.

You should not use anything with `internal` in the package name. These are not part of the Eclipse API and are subject to change without notice.

Make sure you have the `org.eclipse.core.resources` plugin in your plugin dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thin is that I've already tried to use IProject, but guess what: the instanceof operator fails... I've already tried switching to the default class loader. No luck, though.

Comment: What do mean by 'switching to the default class loader'? Eclipse should be managing class loaders and you should not be doing anything with them. You are running this as an Eclipse plugin?

Comment: Yes I am. I read this article: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_use_the_context_class_loader_in_Eclipse%3F about eclipse class loaders, but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: You should just put the resources plugin in your plugin dependencies and not do anything at all with class loaders. If that is not enough we need to see code.